# svg: activate/deactivate animations

Tags: svg, jquery-animate

Short question: is there a way to activate/deactivate SVG <animate> elements, so that only one applies for a given graphical object at a given time?

I have an svg document (<svg></svg>) inlined in a html document. There is one graphical object in the svg, e.g. a circle, and two <animate> elements defined when mouse hovers over the circle. These two animations are unrelated, they implement different animations for the same circle, only one <animate> should be active at a given time. I would like to toggle between the two <animate> elements, so I need to deactivate the current active <animate> and activate the other. How can I do that?

Comment: Set/clear the begin attribute so that the animate does/doesn't start.

Comment: Thx. The problem with that is when reactivating, I need the content of the begin attribute. So before clearing it, I would need to store it in a variable which would be a pain. Thats because the question above is just a simplified version of the problem at hand, I actually have about 50 animated objects with 4-8 animate elements for each (this is a map with various neighborhoods with animations). Something that I collect the animate elements into a group or another separate svg and activate/deactivate the whole group or svg in one go would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could structure your animations like this:

```
<circle id="c1" .../>
<animate xlink:href="#c1"/>
<animate xlink:href="#c2"/>
```

If you change the id of the circle from c1 to c2 then the second animation will apply instead of the first.

Comment: Yeah seems to be a viable workaround... Hope it won't be a problem to point to something that does not exists! thx!

Comment: i clicked on it, is that what you meant?